# How to make all items the same width in a wrappable flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of items of variable width inside of a wrappable `flex` box.

I want all items to have the same width, so I applied the following CSS attributes: `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-grow: 1`. With that, each item in every column should have had the same width, independently from its original width.

This was the expected result, which can be achieved by using `flex-basis: 30%`.

[image: This]

Unfortunately, this won't work in all cases (if the width of each item is small, there will be a lot of empty space).

Using a fixed width does not solve the issue, because each item can occupy different amounts of space.

This can help illustrate de problem, the "large items" create 5 rows (width of 33% per item) while the "small items" create only 3 rows (width of 20% per item).

[image: This]

I'm also not allowed to use JavaScript.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Long long long name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
    <li>Short name</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:**
I had a misconception about the way flexboxes work. The solution here is to use an appropriate value for `flex-basis`.

Comment: You gonna need `inline-flex`, `column` direction and fixed height on the parent to accomplish that: https://jsfiddle.net/qLzca963/

Comment: It partially solves the problem, @LGSon. But what if I don't know the height beforehand? It just overflows if there are a lot of items.

Comment: Then the only way is with script. Do note, there is no other way to allow for a column to size by its smallest item, unless you wrap them in 3 columns by changing the markup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want all items to have the same width, so I applied the following CSS attributes: `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-grow: 1`.

That's a wrong approach. With `flex-grow` you are distributing free space in the container. Since the length of the content is different in each item, the free space will be different in each line. Hence, the columns won't align across rows, despite each item having `flex-basis: 0`.

> With that, each item in every column should have had the same width, independently from its original width.

Actually, per the info I posted above, *"With that, each item in every **row** should have had the same width, independently from its original width."*

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
</ul>
```

You also need to keep in mind that a flex item, by default, cannot shrink past the size of its content, despite `flex-basis: 0`. See here: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

Here's a solution that may be useful:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 1 0 26%; /* see note below */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long long long name</li>
  <li>Long name</li>
  <li>Short name</li>
</ul>
```

*Note regarding `flex-basis: 26%`:*

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand (see `li`), there's no need for `flex-basis` / `width` to be 33.33%, which could result in two items per row if you decide to add vertical margins.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. In this case, with `flex-basis: 26%`, there's plenty of space for margins, the row is filled precisely, and there is not enough space for a fourth item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific width:

```
li{
   flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

Or

```
li{
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
```